# Adding to PATH for programs opened from the desktop

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, desktop-icons

Ok, I know there are lots of ways to add to PATH. Each one has good reasons why you would choose a specific method vs another.

However, what I don't know is in the case of a program opened from the desktop (by double clicking its icon), how does one add to the PATH in this scenario?

By right-clicking and going to properties I can change the command run by double clicking. Could i potentially use && to tag on a command here? Surely there's a better, more global way of doing it?

Not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm using 18.04.

Suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Use `~/.profile`. It's sourced by the display manager and alters `PATH` for the whole session.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - this did the trick globally. The other two suggested answers would have required manually editing each desktop icon individually. If you put this down as an answer I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `~/.profile`. It's sourced by the display manager and alters `PATH` for the whole session.

Comment: This is the solution which worked as it applied the change for all desktop icons in one go rather than needing to do each one individually.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the shortcut's command with a pointer to a `bash` script, set up your environment in the script, then call the shortcut's command.

Answer (score 1):

Every `*.desktop` file has `Exec=` field. This field may include:

- executable name which is already in `$PATH`;
- full path to executable which is not in `$PATH`;
- full path to user/system-created script which does what is needed.

Documentation to read: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables .

Traditional desktop environments like MATE have special tool for desktop-file creation named `mate-desktop-item-edit`. See its [man-page online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man1/mate-desktop-item-edit.1.html).